# Can augmented reality be a training system for computer vision?

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision

Is augmented reality a training system for computer vision? As in, Augmented systems use their data to help train computer vision algorithms, or is augmented reality computer vision itself?

Answer (score 1):

Let me re-frame your question before answering:

> Can augmented reality be a training system for computer vision?

Yes, why not! Also, I'm pretty sure the big companies who have their aug. reality products out there are secretly optimizing their CV algorithms(although we'll have no proof).

A very similar(but a different) example would be how Comma.ai's app pays users for recording their driving, and then uses it to train their own self-driving cars.

So, if that can be done, I don't see why augmented reality cannot be used to train CV algos. In fact, it's a much more richer, localized dataset.

Comment: Noted and corrected. Thank you.

I thought it would make sense, since it is quite rich data. From what i understand about AR, it is analyzing its field of view which is also what CV will do.. right?

 This Comma.ai is new to me, is it similar to what Andy Rubin is doing with dash cams? Or at least plans to do with them? Giving them out for free with state of the art CV to build a network of connected dash cam data, real time.

Comment: @James Yeah, something like that. Comma.ai's app records your driving videos. You need to install the cam on your windshield, and it keeps recording, and that footage is used in their self-driving cars example.